# Passing Multiple Variables Between Functions-Python

Tags: python, oop, closures, decorator

The code below returns NameError: name 'c' is not defined. The score function provides return values for c,d but I am having a difficult time passing them into the adjust function to get e,f output. How can I get c,d into the adjust function?

```
def score():
    a=1
    b=2
    def outcome_1():
        c=a+1
        d=b-1
        return c,d
    def outcome_2():
        c=a+2
        d=b-2
        return c,d
    if a>0:
        outcome_1()
    elif a<0:
        outcome_2()


def adjust(score_results):
    def adjust_1():
        e=c+5
        f=d+4
        print(e,f)
    def adjust_2():
        e=c+4
        f=d+5
        print(e,f)

    adjust_1()

x=score()
adjust(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add a return in the score function, at the moment only the outcome function returns the values, then it remains only in the scope of the score function

As it was also suggested by [quamrana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4834/quamrana) you should consider changing your if conditions, I've added a suggestion as a comment

```
def score():
    a=1
    b=2
    def outcome_1():
        c=a+1
        d=b-1
        return c,d
    def outcome_2():
        c=a+2
        d=b-2
        return c,d
    # Here you should consider changing it to if - else or adding >= 0 in order to cover all possible options
    if a>0:
        return outcome_1()
    elif a<0:
        return outcome_2()
```

Then, you pass x as an argument to the functions adjust wich is the right thing to do, but you don't use the parameter score_results which holds the pointer for your argument x (that you have passed)
So you can define c and d in the begining of your adjust function in order to have theses variables inside the scope of adjust:

```
def adjust(score_results):
    c, d = score_results
    def adjust_1():
        e=c+5
        f=d+4
        print(e,f)
    def adjust_2():
        e=c+4
        f=d+5
        print(e,f)

    adjust_1()

x=score()
adjust(x)
```

Comment: The OP may still get a surprise if on the first line of `score()` there is ever `a=0`.

Answer (score -1):

first of all you are not returning anything when you call outcome_1 and outcome_2,
secondly when you return multiple values from function it returns a tuple containing those values hence you need to access it in that manner inside adjust function. You can not expect python to understand that score_results contains c and d, it merely just has values of both the variables as tuples. Here is the modifications you need to do in your code.

```
def score():
    a=1
    b=2
def outcome_1():
    c=a+1
    d=b-1
    return c,d
def outcome_2():
    c=a+2
    d=b-2
    return c,d
if a>0:
    return outcome_1()
elif a<0:
    return outcome_2()


def adjust(score_results):
    def adjust_1():

        e=score_results[0]+5
        f=score_results[1]+4
        print(e,f)
    def adjust_2():

        e=score_results[0]+4
        f=score_results[1]+5
        print(e,f)

    adjust_1()

x=score()
adjust(x)
```